# Set cell value with getCell() in table Excel JS

Tags: office-js, exceljs

I'm stuck on this and can't find an answer on any website. I'm trying to set the value of the cell but I'm getting the following error:

The property "values" isn't loaded. Please call the load method and context.sync() ...

I do understand I need to call the load method but none of the loads I tried work.

```js
    Excel.run(function (context) {
       var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
       var FilledTable = sheet.tables.getItem(randomId);
       FilledTable.rows.load("items"); //Tried this and many others...
       FilledTable.getDataBodyRange().load("values");

       return context.sync().then(function () {
          FilledTable.getRange().getCell(1,0).values = [[ "test" ]]; //Trying to do this! 
       });
    }
```

Thank you for any help !!

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to loop the first column of my table and set an hyperlink using the value already set.

Example: Complete example

```js
    Excel.run(function (context) {
      var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      var filledTable = sheet.tables.getItem(randomId);
      var usedRange = filledTable.getRange().load("values, rowCount");

      return context.sync().then(function () {
         var keyPos = headers.indexOf("Key");
         if(keyPos > -1){
            for(var z = 1; z < usedRange.rowCount; z++){
               usedRange.values[z][0].hyperlink = {
                  address: `url` + usedRange.values[z][0],
                  documentReference: null,
                  screenTip: null,
                  textToDisplay: usedRange.values[z][0],
                };
              }
           }
         });
       })
```

Comment: J, you don't need to call load() to set values or any other properties on a Office JS proxy object. A call to load() is only needed when you want to get / read properties from Excel. If you give me a few more details about what you want to accomplish with the table object, then I can help you along with a code snippet.

Comment: @JakobNielsen I updated my question with what I want to accomplish

Comment: One thing that I noticed. `FilledTable.getDataBodyRange().load("values")` will load values into a proxy Range object (which your code does not assign to a variable). But your code after the sync does not use that loaded proxy object. By calling `FilledTable.getRange().getCell()`, you are creating an entirely new Range proxy object that does not have its values loaded. I recommend that you start with `var usedRange = FilledTable.getDataBodyRange().load("values")`. Then after the sync, call `getCell` on the `usedRange` object instead an entirely new Range object.

Comment: @RickKirkham you are right, but I still get an issue trying to access values. Using getCell on the used Range works just fine but if I try .values I get the same error than before. Thank you for your help still

Comment: Thanks. I understand better now what you are trying to do. `getCell` also creates a new Range object. So `getCell().values` is trying to read the values of an object whose values have not been loaded. Try reading `usedRange.values` and looping through them creating a hyperlink with each value and assigning it to the corresponding cell of the `usedRange`. Also, please provide the whole of your `Excel.run` method including the loop.

Comment: Updated my example, I'm now getting the following error (because .values is returning a string and not a reference of the cell): TypeError: Cannot create property 'hyperlink' on string 'RS-68'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by using getRow and getColumn instead of values! Here's the fixed code:

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {
  var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  var filledTable = sheet.tables.getItem(randomId);
  var usedRange = filledTable.getRange().load("values, rowCount");

  return context.sync().then(function () {
    var keyPos = headers.indexOf("Key");
    if(keyPos > -1){
      for(var z = 1; z < usedRange.rowCount; z++){
        usedRange.getRow(z).getColumn(keyPos).hyperlink = {
          address: `url` + usedRange.values[z][keyPos],
          documentReference: null,
          screenTip: null,
          textToDisplay: usedRange.values[z][keyPos],
        };
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: J, glad you found a solution building on Ricky's comments. Here is a link to my solution: https://gist.github.com/jakobpn/02716fdc16b34e331669c96589a6089b which you can try in Script lab (http://aka.ms/getscriptlab). It is very similar to what you already have.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution and your time!

Comment: Anytime! Keep asking questions and thanks for exploring Excel add-ins. We are curious about what you are building.